# Bitmap.extractAlpha() do not return any value

Tags: android, image

I try to show a simple bitmap with below code snippets.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap.extractAlpha());
```

*ImageView* visible as empty.

Answer (score 0):

If your original bitmap is opaque then extractAlpha will return a mask that is basically black.

By default your view's background is black so in your case you are setting black on black which is why you can't see it.

Try setting your background to white and see what happens. Something like this:

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap.extractAlpha());
```